# Format of codes

Tags: packages, formatting

For example, in .wl file, I typed a symbol like this,
[image]

However, When I reopen the file, it becomes like this.[image]
How can I keep expression of the form of first picture in .wl file?

Comment: you can try some of the options here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327411/is-there-a-way-around-using-and-for-part-in-mathematica